# Query failed with error code 13 with name 'Unauthorized' in mongodb find query

Tags: java, mongodb, wildfly

I working on mongodb driver migration in my Java J2EE application. Previously we use this dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now we use this one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

We have an admin database with one collection that containing documents.
The previous connection method was implemented like this :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverList, Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createCredential(username, "admin", password.toCharArray())), builder.build());
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setMapSubPackages(true);
morphia.mapPackage(entitiesPackage);
Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "mycollection");
```

And now we have :

```
CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build();
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), CodecRegistries.fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));
MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(uri);
MongoCollection collection = client.getDatabase("admin").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).getCollection("mycollection");
```

with this connection string :

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@<mongodb_server_address>:27017
```

This connection is OK because in starting of my wildfly I can see the log who say Mongodb connected but when the application try to get data from mongodb database using this syntax :

```
collection.find(MyEntity.class).first();
```

we have this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 with name 'Unauthorized' and error message 'not authorized on admin to execute command { find: "mycollection", filter: {}, limit: 1, singleBatch: true }' on server mongodb_server_address:27017
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    ... 8 more
```

It's not credential because with older version everythings work fine and

Answer (score 1):

I fix my probleme like this :

connection string :

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@<my_server_address>:27017/<dbname>?authSource=admin

CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build();
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), CodecRegistries.fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));
MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(uri);
MongoDatabse database = client.getDatabase(dbName).withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
```